# 100+ column with 10 rows rendering performance is very worst in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-grid

If I have 1000+ rows with 10 to 30 columns it works fine, 
but if I have 10 rows with 200+ columns, rendering takes 2 to 3 minutes.

After some time, the data is not visible while horizontal scrolling.
Eventually, the page becomes unresponsive.

The code is here :

```
$http.post($scope.url + "/getPagingRecordImportedTable", {
    dbname : $stateParams.dbname,
    tableName : tablename,
    pageNumber : 1 
}).success(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response.records;
    $scope.mdata = response.metadata;
    $scope.gridOptions.data = response.records;
    var columnsize = 0;
    for (var obj in $scope.mdata) {
        if ($scope.mdata[obj]['columnsize'] > 20) {
            columnsize = 20;
        } else {
            columnsize = $scope.mdata[obj]['columnsize'];
        }
        $scope.columns.push({
            field : $scope.mdata[obj]['columnname'],
            width : columnsize
        });
    }
    console.log("-----------Data received");
})
```

After firing http request the `-------------Data received` log is immediately printed, but rendering data takes too much time.

How can improve performance? Or is there any other API for huge rows and 200+ columns?!

Comment: Paginate. If you want the user to experience 'seamless' loading, then implement ajax to conceal the pagination; data is loaded as the user scrolls.

Comment: If you HAVE to display that many row without paging, I'd suggest you to use a timeout to render x rows at a time. And not using angular for doing this. But paging is clearly the best answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar thing last year and summarised my thoughts in an article [Rendering large data with AngularJS 1.4 (ft. Polymer 0.5)](http://ahoj.io/rendering-large-data-with-angularjs-1-4-ft-polymer).

Basically, [I recommend](http://ahoj.io/rendering-large-data-with-angularjs-1-4-ft-polymer#10-switch-to-polymer-s-lt-core-list-gt-lt-iron-list-gt-in-polymer-1-0) using [`<iron-list>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list) from Polymer components although it requires some refactoring (depending on your use case).

If you can't or don't want to use `<iron-list>` try to use [one-time bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) as much as possible.

Comment: please tell me relevant to ui-grid because i implemented in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue by letting watchers fire individually for rows and columns.
I was earlier updating gridOptions.colDefs and gridOptions.data together. Then changed it to:

1. gridOptions.colDefs = new settings...
2. $timeout(function() { gridOptions.data = new data... },500, true);

And it works like charm. Obviously, one can adjust timeout values by hitting and trialing out on data and columns length.